using the += operator on a string in dart does nothing
I am trying to add some character to the end of a string and the program does it correctly  once but fails to do it a second time and in terms of syntax it looks impossible anyone got any idea why it might be this way?
this is the part of the code that looks absurd:
print("barcodeString: $barcodeString");
print("eventChar: ${event.character}");
barcodeString += event.character!;
print("barcodeString: $barcodeString");

this is the output:
I/flutter ( 6374): barcodeString: 
I/flutter ( 6374): eventChar: 9
I/flutter ( 6374): barcodeString: 

the += operator works initially but after I assign "" to barcodeString at some point in the code it stops working what might be the reason?
I am trying the reset the string when encountering a certain character and it worked fine but after I reset the barcodeString to "" with barcodeString = ""; the += operator stops working on barcodeString.
Here is the shortest sample of the code I could produce that still makes sense.

  RawKeyboard.instance.addListener(_scanner.scannerListener);
  // Some stream that provides instances of RawKeyboardEvents which contains .character property a nullable String
  String _barcodeString = "";
  //The string that I am manipulating and trying to output
  void scannerListener(RawKeyEvent event){
    //event.character is the String representation of the event from the stream it is nullable
    if(event.character!=null&&event.character!="\n"){
      _barcodeString += event.character!;
      //after _barcodeString = ""; this line does not change the value of _barcodeString
    }else if(event.character=="\n"){
      //calling the method to reset the barcodeString
      print(barcodeReadComplete());
    }
  }

  String barcodeReadComplete(){
    final String barcode = _barcodeString;
    _barcodeString = "";
    //I reset the string after I recieve the newline character from the stream after]
    //which the += operator stops changing the value of barcodeString
    return barcode;
  }


I can't reproduce this behaviour. Please post a [mcve].

the app consists of a single file. I will add the whole code of the main file here. I am experiencing all sorts of unexpected behavior right now and have no idea which direction to take. I am using a barcode scanner that behaves as a hardware keyboard the input of which I listen with a RawKeyboard.instance .

@Rufat-dev Rather than explaining in words in a comment, please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to include the definitions os barcodeString and event in such a way that we can copy/paste/run the code to reproduce the behavior. Including an additional link to a Dartpad or Zapp.run repro also never hurts.

I mentioned that I will add it which I already did. To reproduce the issue completely you might need a hardware keyboard connected to the android device even though the issue itself does not seem like it arises from the keyboard but a matter of simple string operation.

@Rufat-dev We need to you to reduce the example down to the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the issue. Part of debugging is tracing the root of the issue. You should be able to work the code you pasted down to several lines of pure Dart code (no flutter should be required if it is a String manipulation issue like you suggest)

This is definitely not an issue with the += operator. Your if and if/else logic is likely not working how you expect with certain key presses. Print out event.character for every event.

Well I reduced it down even more and tested and the issue seems to be that there is some char that when added to the string makes the string completely dysfunctional. Now I want to learn what that is because I am clearly not adding null to the string it has to be some possible value of the type string:
if(event.character!=null&&event.character!="\n")
{
_barcodeString += event.character!;
}

Character 9 is an invisible tab character, no?

The last character is the down arrow on the keyboard but what is the string equivalent of this? it shows as an invisible character when I print it and its not null either and it makes the string stop working all together.
